# call 2 functions inside same class with the same entry

Tags: php, function, class

lets imagine i have this functions

```
class xx {
    function one() {
        echo "hello";
    }
    function two() {
        echo "how are you";
    }
}
```

if i do this

```
$call = new xx;
$call->one();
```

this will print hello on the page
but if i want to print hello how are you can i do something like this?

```
$call->one()->two();
```

??? because i tried that and it prints me hello only, how can i call the second function with one sentence only?
also tryed

```
$call = new xx();
$calboth = $call->one();

$callboth->two();
```

but just print hellohello anyway, so how can i do it? to print both?
my point is not printing but making 2 functions work in same call

for example function dbconnect and login or dbconnect and register, inside same class
and include the class php on main file and call only with something like i said before

```
$login = new system;
$login->dbconnect()->login();
```

thanks for all awnsers

Comment: First hint: `$call->one()->two()` is an expression that is equivalent to this: `$tmp = $call->one(); $tmp->two();` Presumably `$tmp` is `null` and `null` doesn't have method `two()` defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To chain methods, you need to return an instance of the class:

```
class xx {
    function one() {
        echo "hello";
        return $this;
    }
    function two() {
        echo "how are you";
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then this should work:

```
$call = new xx;
$call->one()->two();
```